# JQuery (this).text is not appending via click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Poorly worded question, but I can't find a better way. Also, checked the 'related' questions and none solve this issue.

I am using JQuery 1.4.2, and JQueryUI 1.8.1.

I have a list of "buttons", and I want those buttons to make a copy of themselves in another list on the page. Here is what I have so far:

```
        $("#actionList ul > li > p").button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-document'
            },
            text: true
        }).click(function () {
            $('#callFlow').find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text((this).text).appendTo('#callFlow');
        });
```

#actionList is the DIV for the unordered list I have. P contain "button" effect.

#callFlow is the DIV for the ordered list, which contains a single li with the class of placeholder.

Most of this is from the shopping cart demo on the JQuery UI site. But I've gone away from draggable/droppable, and simply want the user to click the button and have it "duplicated" in the other list. No sorting is needed, as it's a flow building application that will eventually load an AJAX div based on the button you click.

Any assistance is great. I hope I was clear enough in describing the issue.

Comment: The above is called during the .ready function.

Comment: Is there a typo in .text((this).text) for .text(jQuery(this).text)

Comment: @Marimuthu - Actually `jQuery(this).text()`  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When getting (or setting) the text you need to call the function, like this:

```
$("<li></li>").text($(this).text()).appendTo('#callFlow');
```

When you call `$(this).text` it's just a reference to the function, you want to actually execute the function and get the result, so use [`$(this).text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: also note the lack of $ in the (this).text in the question

Comment: This didn't fix my issue, but I believe it fixed the actual problem to the code posted above when no other code is present. Going to mark as solved. Time to dig through my pile of junk code and find where else I missed some syntax.